# Animating a heatmap over time using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api, heat-map, flask

I'm currently building a web application using flask and google maps api.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a page where user can select the time using a slider bar and the google maps api will display a animated heatmap of that duration to see how the heatmap clusters move over that period.

Comment: never used flask but animate heat maps are possible > http://jsfiddle.net/px8kgvjb/2/